# Is it possible to have expressions in dplyr tibbles?

Tags: r, dplyr, expression, tibble

I'm using `dplyr`, `kabble`, and `kableextra` to create some tables in R. I'm converting the `tibble` outputs from `dpylr` chains for tables in a report. I'd like to have the rank included as a column in a `tibble` that I then pipe into a `kabble` table. Is there a way to do this using mark-up or perhaps an R package that has the numeric expressions for ranks (i.e., 1st, 2nd, 3rd)?

I've tried this, but with many ranks it is impractical. Something similar to `LETTERS` would be good.

```
expression('1^st')
expression('2^nd')
```

Comment: As for the *ordinals* (or *ranks*) see `english::ordinal` on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/english/index.html) or the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/english/versions/1.1-4/topics/ordinal).

Comment: You can't make an atomic vector of expressions in R, but you can hold them in a list, which can be a column of a tibble, e.g. `tibble(expr = list(expression(1^st), expression(2^nd)))`. If you're quoting already, though, just use a character vector.

Comment: @alistaire, thanks. Would you know of a package that might have these listed out? (or is this an opportunity to try my hand at making a package?). Thanks.

Comment: Ordinals? See the `english` package linked by Rui above. I've considered doing some more stuff to make [Unicode CLDR](https://github.com/unicode-cldr) more accessible from R, but I haven't done it yet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for ordinals, but expressions (I think) - like, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4rth, 5th, etc. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `scales::ordinal`, though you'll have to insert the `^` and coerce to an expression if you want it formatted that way